# What's the difference between has entered and entered?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

My uncle has entered many sailing boat races.
-In the past but I don't say when.

My uncle entered a sailing boat race in 2014 and won.
-In the past but I say when.

What's the difference between has entered and entered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I have never said" versus "I never said"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15535/i-have-never-said-versus-i-never-said)

Comment: The difference is exactly as you state it.

Comment: @marcellothearcane No, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Use the present perfect to refer to something that happened at some unspecified time before right now. Use the past simple for something that happened at some specified point in the past.

Answer (score -2):

Both are correct, there is no difference in both.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: They are both correct, okay, but there is difference in both.

Comment: Agree, difference is there, it's only about the way you present it, nothing else is different. Meaning in case remains same, so how you consider it as different?